# How does the setup bootstrapper detect if prerequisites are installed?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

Trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591384/bootstrapper-setup-exe-says-net-3-5-not-found-but-launching-msi-directly-in).

I would like to learn how the bootstrapper detects if prerequisites (specifically .NET 3.5) are installed.

According to [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716.aspx), a way to detect if .NET is installed is to check the following registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5`

Using process monitor, I have inspected registry queries done by the bootstrapper (setup.exe) and it did not show any access to this registry key.

**Does anybody know how the bootstrapper determines whether the prerequisites are installed on the target system?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prerequisite packages for the msbuild GenerateBootStrapper packages are defined as XML files. The schema of those XML files is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223(v=VS.80).aspx). Take a look at the "InstallChecks" element to get an idea of what sort of checks are possible.

Curiously enough, I could not find such install checks in the prerequisite package for .NET 3.5. You can find this package in the windows SDK folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows), along with the other predefined bootstrapper packages.

Comment: For some reason, the install checks for .Net seem to be in the localized part of the package (see package.xml under Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1\en)

Comment: Thanks Wim and Damien, this solves our problem. This problem happens on German Windows 7 installations and the build machine has only \en subfolder in the SDK Bootstrapper directory. The en subfolder contains a package.xml with registry check for \1033 subkey of the .NET registry key (<RegistryCheck Property="DotNet35InstallSuccess" Key="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\1033" Value="Install" />). This is not present on the default german Windows 7 installations for some reason.

Comment: Tweaking the package.xml on the build machine solved the problem, but I am still interested in the real source of the problem and whether this is a bug in Windows 7 (whether the 1033 subkey should be present even on German Windows 7) or in the bootstrapper (checks incorrect key)